# Create a Pandas scatter plot, where one of the axes is the index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

If I have a data frame, where I want to create a scatter plot of a column against the index, is there a way simpler than using `matplotlib` directly, or create a list out of the index, etc? Something like this:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='index', y='price')
```

I am assuming that this won't work, because an index might consist of multiple series and Pandas won't know which to draw upon, without further indication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Temporarily reset the index and treat it just like any other column:

```
df.reset_index().plot.scatter(x='level_0', y='price')
```